# Best console editor for writing a ... novel? :)

Tags: linux, text-editors

there, ladies and gentlemen :)

I started to write a novel, and cause it's mostly IT stuff - I decided to make all the things around this book - as IT as possible.
So, I started to write it in the terminal, I'm on Linux, and more specifically - in nano. But, the more the text grows, the more I feel uncomfortable - it doesn't have word-wrapping, the page down / page up works so badly, and finally - today a colleague of mine told me that there is a chance for the whole terminal to shut down suddenly, erasing all the text you've written from the last save.

So, can you recommend me editor? I want it to have these things I mentioned above.

PS: Tried emacs and vim a while ago - writing code, not some big plain text - but I'm not sure they have these, and also - I prefer no highlighting of the text.
PS2: And also - if it has dictionary and mark the wrong words - it would be soooo perfect ... :) ...

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: vim has word-wrapping (as long as you don't indent the code) and spell checking, you can disable syntax highlighting, and supports very big files.

Comment: [La]TeX is great if you want to focus on content rather than layout. The markup is done in text format, though files are rendered after compilation.

Comment: emacs and vim are generally the go-to console text editors in Linux. [La]TeX is the go-to markup language for formatting the text, if you're not going to use an Office suite (or anything WYSIWYG).

Comment: Are you planning on publishing the novel in the traditional way?  Or even as an e-book?  Consider the publisher requirements, because they'll trump whatever you want to use.

Comment: If I were you, I would just type this into a text file normally, save it normally. then have the terminal display it. Or create a .exe/.bat/thingie from a text editor that, by default, when clicked, will spawn a program that runs in the terminal.

Comment: Too subjective.  Voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: I'll have to add my vote for emacs. When combined with [La]TeX and flyspell-mode (for spell checking as you type), it is perfect for your needs. I wrote my entire PhD thesis on emacs.

Comment: If you work a lot in a terminal, you ought to use Tmux. With Tmux you can keep your sessions alive even when your terminal dies; you can connect remotely and take over an existing session; etc. It's extremely handy.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest `vim`. It's near infinitely extensible, and the uncluttered interface makes it the perfect place to focus on writing.

It would be a much better experience with some tweaks. For instance, see [Writing Prose with Vim](http://alols.github.com/2012/11/07/writing-prose-with-vim/) for tips regarding wrapping, spellcheck, and how to export it to a high quality output.

For writing in a text editor, something like Markdown would be perfect for basic markup. If the filename ends with .md it will autodetect it and syntax highlight it, though you can turn that off if you wish with `syntax off`.

If you do use vim, you would do well to get some familiarity with its rather unique workflow using the many sites that will help. [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) is a great place to start.

Crashing will also not be an issue. Vim has swap files that will allow autorecovery of your work in the event of a crash.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want the software you use to be a command line interface, and it to be designed for typing text, you'd be better off searching for applications from before proper GUIs existed, because no one would bother making one like that now. Seriously, who wants to type a text without being able to use the mouse to select text, and without any formating options?

Something from the early 1990s or 1980s. Look for what "futuristic" secretaries who had a computer used. A quick search fetches:

- WordStar
- Textor
- Manuscript
- Corel WordPerfect (still exists, but has had a long life since 1980)
- Borland Sprint
- Isofting eWriter Wisto

This link seems to fetch you quite a few more choices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_word_processors#Historical

Once you choose one, you work to make it work on your modern OS through some kind of emulation. Good luck. :p

Comment: Those seem to be Windows editors; he's writing on Linux. Also, plenty of people don't want to use the mouse, and people still work on console editors (`nano` was written in 1999, well past the advent of GUIs).

Comment: @cpast I know they're (mostly?) for Windows, but I thought Linux excelled at emulating, so.

Comment: You can select text with the mouse just fine in a console editor.